# Angular 1: Change md-checkbox depending on input checkbox

Tags: angularjs

How do I change check status of `md-checkbox` from Angular material depending on the actual checkbox check status?

Here are my checkboxes. They are inside `ng-repeat`.

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.completed" ng-model="toDoItemCheckbox">
    <md-checkbox
      ng-change="toggleToDoItem({{item.createdAt}})" ng-model="toDoItemCheckbox" aria-label="todo-checkbox">
    </md-checkbox>
```

Comment: can you post what you have tried in your controller? or directive?

Comment: @inspired here is whole controller for this partial http://i.imgur.com/5QYXI57.png  (had to screenshot it, wouldn't be readable inside a comment)

Comment: can you post your controller div and your ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a input type check box when you already have a md-checkbox. 
The checked status of md-checkbox can be changed depending on model.

```
<section class="white-frame-z1" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.status" ng-click="toggleTodo(todo)" />Regular Checkbox
        <md-checkbox ng-model="todo.status">
          {{todo.name}}
        </md-checkbox>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
  </section>
```

Check this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/aNyrBx) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You could do so by simply using `ng-model`for two-way data binding:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in toDoItems">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.complete">
    <md-checkbox
      ng-change="toggleToDoItem({{item.createdAt}})" ng-model="item.complete" aria-label="todo-checkbox">
    </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

See this [Code Pen.](http://codepen.io/codekhalifah/pen/mPMZEp)